# Adding user to ActiveMQ Artemis fails on Windows

Tags: windows, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to add a user to ActiveMQ Artemis on Windows. I have created an instance and started it. Then I run command:

```
artemis user add --user admin --password admin --user-command-user another_admin --user-command-password another_admin  --role admin --url tcp://localhost:61616
```

The command fails with message:

> The system cannot find the path specified.
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> Connection brokerURL = tcp://localhost:61616
> Failed to add user another_admin. Reason: AMQ229220: Failed to load user file: /C:/Program%20Files/apache-artemis-2.26.0-instance1/etc/artemis-users.properties

How to fix?

Comment: I just set up a Windows VM, installed JDK 17, downloaded & unzipped ActiveMQ Artemis 2.26.0, created a broker instance, and ran the `artemis.cmd user add` command and added a user without any problems. Please provide steps to reproduce the error you're seeing. It looks like it may be environmental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4049) related to how the broker deals with spaces in the path to the user/role files. I've sent [a PR](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/pull/4259) to resolve the problem. The fix should be in 2.27.0.

In the mean-time you can work-around the issue by putting the broker instance on a path which has no spaces.